# How do you replace commands in the terminal?

Tags: terminal

I want to be able to type a short command and have that be replaced with a longer one. For example, typing `vscode` could run something like `open -a "Visual Studio Code"`. I know this is possible in Linux, but is there any way to do this in MacOS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do the same as your were doing in **Linux** in **macOS**.

As an example, if using `bash`, adding

```
alias vscode="open -a 'Visual Studio Code'"
```

to your `.bash_profile` *file* will let you just type `vscode` in **Terminal**  to open **Visual Studio Code**.

---

<sub>Note: If you are running **macOS Catalina**, or later, and have not installed a more recent version of `bash` and are using the default `zsh` *shell*, then put `aliases` in your `~/.zprofile`, or the appropriate *file* for the *shell* you are running.</sub>

Also, you might want to read [Visual Studio Code on macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#:%7E:text=Launching%20from%20the%20command%20line,code%27%20command%20in%20PATH%20command) to add the `code` executable to your `PATH` or `path`, depending on your *shell*.

Comment: Better answer than mine.  But mine should work. Takes a little longer.  I have about 30 aliases in my .bash_profile file yet I didn't even think of doing it that way!  lol

Comment: Note that starting in macOS Catalina, the default interactive shell is zsh, so you'd put that in `~/.zprofile` instead of `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Or you could just follow VS Code's published instructions, at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#:~:text=Launching%20from%20the%20command%20line,code'%20command%20in%20PATH%20command .  But no one reads instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a series of 1 line scripts and make them executable. In your example, a script named vscode would contain the one line you describe above. then you could

`chmod +x vscode`

and then just type vscode and return to run it.

Comment: You need to first add a [_shebang_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and then your _script code_, so not really one-liners.